# Conditional Covariance Matrix

Tags: conditional-probability, covariance-matrix, definition

For the conditional covariance matrix, is the notation $\operatorname{cov}(\textbf{X}\mid Y)$ elegimate? where $ \textbf{X} $ is a random vector, and $Y$ is a random variable. I find the definition of conditional covariance matrix for a random vector in the [lecture notes of PSU](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~ajw13/stat505/fa06/08_partcor/03_partcor_mvc.html), but is there any assumption before the definition? (e.g. is there any requirement for $ \textbf{X}$ and $ Y $?) And how could I find the accurate definition in a publication? Thank you!

Comment: What's the matter with the definition supplied in those lecture notes? It looks perfectly standard and rigorous.  In what way do you deem it not "accurate"?

Comment: It may help to note that X|Y is itself a random variable, so you can find its covariance like any other rv.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problems with the definitions, in fact, $X \mid Y$ is itself a random variable so any definitions for random variables can be applied to it.  See here:  [Interpretation of Total Law of Covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179129/interpretation-of-total-law-of-covariance)   for use  and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance) for other use.